# What is difference between breed, variant, subspecies and species?

Tags: taxonomy

What is the difference between breed, variant, sub-species and species? Are there any similarities between sub-species and sub-population of a region?

Comment: what do you mean by "*Are there any similarities between sub-species and sub-population of a region?*"?

Comment: You may want to add the term `strain` in you list. @WYSIWYG I would guess that the OP asked between sub-species and sub-population of a region because (s)he has some understanding that species is a term that applies to taxonomy while population is a concept that is used to define a collection of individuals that reproduce and live over a geographical region.

Answer (score 6):

A **species** is commonly defined as the largest group within which interbreeding produces viable offspring.

A **sub-species** is a subgroup below the level of a species.  One definition is a group which can interbreed successfully with other subspecies, but does not do so in practice (e.g. due to geographical isolation).  Other terms like **variety**, **form**, etc., may be used in some domains to indicate various groupings below the species level.

A **breed** usually refers to a population of a domestic animal that has been selectively bred for specific characteristics.

A **population** is a set of individuals within a species that live in the same geographical region.  Depending on rates of gene flow, different populations within a species may eventually differentiate into subspecies or distinct species — this is known as [allopatric speciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allopatric_speciation).

Comment: So is there any difference in meaning between `population` and `subspecies`? Note that while you are giving the most commonly used definition of species, those definition only apply to lineages that reproduce sexually. I would love to have the definition of the word `strain` as well in this list. I would tend to think that many of these concepts are poorly defined and are used with different definitions in different field of biology.

Comment: @Remi.b These concepts are indeed loosely defined and the accepted definitions vary across different subdomains (e.g. microbiology vs botany vs zoology); this is just an overview.  As for population versus subspecies, population just refers to the members of a taxon in a given region, with no implication of a distinct genetic lineage.

Comment: As Remi said, what is strain actually?