# How are subspecies defined, in contrast to species?

Tags: taxonomy, species

When should a taxon be considered to be a subspecies of a certain species, and when as a different species? Are there some general guidelines how to assign a specific taxonomic status to a taxon?

Comment: This Q is more similar to [*What is a subspecies?*](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/38753/what-is-a-subspecies), and should be closed as a duplicate to that question.

Comment: Also see the questions http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26105/what-is-difference-between-breed-variant-subspecies-and-species and http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/14414/3624