# Taxonomy and 'breeds' of animal species

Tags: taxonomy, classification

How do taxonomists classify *breeds* of organisms in a species? When talking in such depths about organisms (using **RNA** *and* **DNA**), don't they have to unavoidably do it?

I read in another [question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/27602/why-cant-we-call-dog-breeds-different-species) that all the breeds of dog we domesticate belong to the **same** species. But they (the dogs) certainly have very apparent differences. Don't they?

So how do taxonomists handle/consider these '***breeds***'?

Comment: Take at look at [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/26105/what-is-difference-between-breed-variant-subspecies-and-species).